# Using ipc in Electron to set global variable from renderer (again)

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm creating an app that can go back and forth between Window 1 to Window 2.  I keep both windows open but hide the one not currently in use using currentWindow.hide().  I want to increment a counter each time I come into Window 2.  I tried to use the code from [Using ipc in Electron to set global variable from renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49715862/using-ipc-in-electron-to-set-global-variable-from-renderer/) to set a global variable and increment it each time I come into Window 2:

**main.js**

```
ipcMain.on('setMyGlobalVariable', (event, myGlobalVariableValue) => {
  global.myGlobalVariable = myGlobalVariableValue;
});
```

**renderer.js**

```
lv = remote.getGlobal("MyGlobalVariable"); // Read
if (lv = null) lv = 0;
lv = lv + 1;
console.log(lv);
ipcRenderer.send("setMyGlobalVariable", lv); // Store New Value
```

Unfortunately, every time I come back to window 2, lv is null! Can this be done, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: myGlobalVariable !== MyGlobalVariable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say how you are managing the showing/hiding of the windows – so there are a few ways to do what you want.

You could keep it within the `Main` context by subscribing to the [show](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-show) event for the window you want to track and just directly increment the counter there. The `focus` even would work the same way, if you are not actually hiding the windows.

```
mainWindow.on('show', event => {
    global.sharedData.counter += 1;
    console.log('counter', global.sharedData.counter);
});
```

---

**From the Render context** – from the docs: [How to share data between web pages?](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/faq#how-to-share-data-between-web-pages)

You can't increment a global property directly from `remote` - this fails:    `remote.getGlobal("counter")+=1;`

but you can change the contents of an object:
`remote.getGlobal("sharedData").counter += 1;`

**Main.js**

```
// initialize the container:
global.sharedData = {counter: 0};

// not needed but just for sanity check
ipcMain.on('app-message', (event, arg) => {
    switch (arg.event) {
        case "log counter":
            console.log('counter', global.sharedData.counter);

        break;
     }
});
```

---

**Renderer context**

```
  // wrapped in a button click function
  $("#counter-btn").on("click", function (e) {


    // *** this is the only line that matters ***   
    remote.getGlobal("sharedData").counter += 1;


    // sanity check
    let c = remote.getGlobal("sharedData").counter;
    console.log('counter', c);

    // tell main to show the value
    ipcRenderer.send('app-message', { event: "log counter" });
  })
```

Comment: Great!  Thank you - that worked.  And since I'm new to both javascript and Electron thanks for including the comments (like *** this is the only line that matters *** ).  That really helped.  Is there anything I'm supposed to do to close this?

Comment: Glad to help. Electron is a lot of fun to work with. If you want to accept the answer, click the check mark in the left sidebar.