# uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined in ElectronJS using example docs

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, ipcmain

## Short intro

I've been following the official Electron docs (https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main)
about communicating from render and main processes, but I can't get it to work.

## The error

While trying the **Sending Messages** example, I get this error in my JS console:
**❌ Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined**

## The example code

This is on my last lines in my **main.js**

```
// In main process.
const { ipcMain } = require('electron')
ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg) // prints "ping"
  event.reply('asynchronous-reply', 'pong')
})

ipcMain.on('synchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg) // prints "ping"
  event.returnValue = 'pong'
})
```

And this is what I have in my **render.js**

```
// In renderer process (web page).
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
console.log(ipcRenderer.sendSync('synchronous-message', 'ping')) // prints "pong"

ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-reply', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg) // prints "pong"
})
ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', 'ping')
```

The error I get is in this part `const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')`

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main#sending-messages

This is how I call my **render.js** inside my `<head>`

```
<script defer src="../scripts/render.js"></script>
```

## Screenshot

[image: screenshot about the error]

## What I tried

I've followed this related Q/A but I still get the same error:
[Using ipc in Electron to set global variable from renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49715862/using-ipc-in-electron-to-set-global-variable-from-renderer)
Also this: [Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined in Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60533857/uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined-in-electron)
And this: ["Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import)

I've seen that some people say that you need to enable **nodeIntegration** in your **main.js**, and yes I have it enabled but still throws the error:

```
const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1280,
    height: 900,
    icon: path.join(__dirname, '../render/assets/favicon.png'),
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    webPrefrerences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    }
  });
```

I also tried converting to **ES6 module syntax**.

```
import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron';
```

While also adding the **type="module"** like this:

```
  <script type="module" defer src="../scripts/render.js"></script>
```

But the error then is:
❌**Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module**

I've been searching for days for a solution here in SO but I couldn't find anything to sort this out, so any help will be appreciated.

## Steps to reproduce the project and error

1. Initialize the project and open up with your desired editor.
   `npx create-electron-app app`
   `cd app`
   `code .`
2. Then edit `index.js` and add `nodeIntegration: true`.
3. Edit your `index.html` to add `<script src="renderer.js"></script>`
4. Create a new file `renderer.js` inside your src folder next to the `index.html` and `index.js` files.
5. Now you should have the following tree:

   +-src
   ---index.css
   ---index.html
   ---index.js (this is your main.js)
   ---renderer.js (this ins your renderer.js)
6. Add the example code to the index.js and renderer.js
7. Run the following command `npm start`, a new window should open with the Electron app running.
8. The console throws the error.
   [image: example error]

Comment: I don't think you're meant to use the script like that?

Comment: care to explain yourself please?

Comment: Their example doesn't have a script tag https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/quick-start#create-a-web-page

Comment: @evolutionxbox I think they do: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/quick-start/#bonus-add-functionality-to-your-web-contents that's the common way to use renderer.js, how other way can you load your clientside website js files if not using an script tag or between your <script> tags inside your html? 

Comment: Then you must transpile the JS first. _"such as using webpack to bundle and minify your code or React to manage your user interfaces."_ - Require does not exist in the browser.

Comment: I just added some steps to reproduce the error in case you guys wanna help out, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Client on Node.js: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-js-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: Thanks man but that link is on my "What I tried" section already! 

Comment: How did you try it? Are you using a build tool to compile the JavaScript first?

Comment: the `npm start` command which is in fact `electron-forge start` already bundles everything inside src as far as I understand. If you follow the `Steps to reproduce the project and error` that I just updated on my question I guarantee that you will have the project working in a minute with the same error as I have.

Comment: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9920 might have a solution for you

Comment: @evolutionxbox Just to let you know, I'm still going through... I've tried like 5 solutions from that link already, and I'm still in the middle of the scroll  I'm not using React ayways but I'm trying some solutions just in case. I need more time to test everything.

Comment: After many changes to the main.js WebPreferences, I still can't get it to work. The preload.js trick was promising but still won't work. I get the same error.

Comment: @evolutionxbox turns out I had a typo, it's **webPreferences** and not **webPrefrerences** as you can read in my What I tried LOL! 

Answer (score 0):

I had a typo in my **main.js**

It is **webPreferences** not webP**r**efrerences!

**nodeIntegration** is **False** by default, that's why I couldn't use require.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!